# Routing specific TCP/UDP packets from VLAN's to proxy server

Tags: proxy, vlan

I need to set up a  solution which is for routing specific TCP/UDP packets between the devices in two separate VLANs through a proxy server. For eg: all my computers are connected to one VLAN(1) and my printers are one another VLAN(2). I can reroute all the packets from VLAN(1) to VLAN(2). My objective is to only reroute packets which generated for printers in VLAN (2) from computers in  VLAN (1).

Is there any way in Layer 3 routing for achieving this?

Answer (score -1):

Normal routing is based on the destination IP address. If you need to select routes based on source IP address or source/destination port numbers you require *policy-based routing*.

What you're describing though is simple, destination-based routing. Just add a route to VLAN 2 on your default gateway (or connect it directly) and you're set. (Obviously, the printers in VLAN 2 need to have a route back as well.)

If you want to limit the routed protocols to the printing specific ones or filter by source address you need to use a firewall or switch/router ACLs.